# SQL complex join query with sum

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, join

I am trying to obtain sum of amounts based on a column(sysprocode) which is unique for the composite key (Organizationunitid and payrollcodeid).So far I have managed to get amount based on Organizationunitid and payrollcodeid but not alongside sysprocode.A look at my **SQLfiddle** should clarify this more [Click](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/434b69/3)
Here I have tried this sql query

```
SELECT TB1.OUId,TB1.OUName,(TB2.Amount - TB3.ManualDeduction) AS amt
FROM 
( 
SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,ou.OrganizationUnitName AS OUName 
FROM OrganizationUnits ou 
) TB1, 
(SELECT e.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,SUM(trn.Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN tblPeriodTransactions trn ON (e.EmployeeID=trn.Employee_ID) 
 where trn.Period_Month =6 and trn.Period_Year=2013 and trn.PayrollCode_ID=2
GROUP BY e.OrganizationUnitID 
)TB2, 
(SELECT e.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,SUM(ep.ManualDeduction) AS ManualDeduction 
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeePension ep ON (e.EmployeeID=ep.Employee_ID) 
GROUP BY e.OrganizationUnitID 
)TB3 
WHERE (TB2.OUId=TB1.OUId) 
AND (TB3.OUId=TB1.OUId)
```

Here is sample output in imgur [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia59Y.jpg)

Comment: What output you want, add sample output data in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally after fumbling about

```
SELECT TB4.Syscode,
CASE TB4.accountType WHEN 'c' THEN concat('-', (TB2.Amount - TB3.ManualDeduction)) 
ELSE (TB2.Amount - TB3.ManualDeduction) end AS amount
FROM 
( 
SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,ou.OrganizationUnitName AS OUName 
FROM OrganizationUnits ou 
) TB1, 
(SELECT e.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,SUM(trn.Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN tblPeriodTransactions trn ON (e.EmployeeID=trn.Employee_ID) 
WHERE trn.Period_Month = 6 
AND trn.Period_Year = 2013 
AND trn.PayrollCode_ID = 2
GROUP BY e.OrganizationUnitID 
)TB2, 

(SELECT e.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,SUM(ep.ManualDeduction) AS ManualDeduction 
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeePension ep ON (e.EmployeeID=ep.Employee_ID) 
GROUP BY e.OrganizationUnitID 
)TB3,
(SELECT ou.OrganizationUnitID AS OUId,sp.sysprocode as Syscode,sp.accountType AS accountType
FROM OrganizationUnits ou    
INNER JOIN sysprocodes sp ON (ou.OrganizationUnitID=sp.organisationunitid) 
INNER JOIN  tblpayrollcode pc ON (pc.PayrollCode_ID = sp.PayrollCode_ID)
where sp.PayrollCode_ID = 2
GROUP BY ou.OrganizationUnitID,sp.sysprocode,sp.PayrollCode_ID,sp.accountType 
)TB4
WHERE (TB2.OUId=TB1.OUId) 
AND (TB3.OUId=TB1.OUId) 
AND(TB4.OUId =tb3.OUId)
```

Click [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/434b69/13) to view the **SQLFIDDLE**

Answer (score 0):

Check the following query whether it is working or not but i think calculating pension is problem because there is no PayrollCode_ID in tblEmployeePension:

```
SELECT 
    OU.OrganizationUnitID,
    OU.OrganizationUnitName,
    SPC.sysprocode,
    PC.PayrollCode_ID,
    SUM(PD.Amount),
    (SELECT SUM(tblEmployeePension.ManualDeduction) FROM tblEmployeePension WHERE Employee_ID IN (SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employees WHERE OrganizationUnitID = OU.OrganizationUnitID)) AS Pension,
    SUM(PD.Amount) - (SELECT SUM(tblEmployeePension.ManualDeduction) FROM tblEmployeePension WHERE Employee_ID IN (SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employees WHERE OrganizationUnitID = OU.OrganizationUnitID)) as amt
FROM 
    tblPeriodTransactions PD
INNER JOIN
    Employees E
ON 
    PD.Employee_ID = E.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
    OrganizationUnits OU
ON
    E.OrganizationUnitID = OU.OrganizationUnitID
INNER JOIN
    tblPayrollCode PC
ON
    PD.PayrollCode_ID = PC.PayrollCode_ID
INNER JOIN
    sysprocodes SPC
ON
    SPC.organisationunitid = OU.OrganizationUnitID AND
    SPC.PayrollCode_ID = PC.PayrollCode_ID
GROUP BY
    OU.OrganizationUnitID,
    PC.PayrollCode_ID,
    SPC.sysprocode,
    OU.OrganizationUnitName
```

Comment: ping me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net gotalove please @sandeep coz this is your soln http://imgur.com/1kqKAbp but this are the values I need http://imgur.com/Wm3IxrN